# Merge json entries with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am making some visualisations and need to merge certain json entries.

The problem is, that the json file that gets called is a bit messed up. Certain entries need to be merged and others should be kept the same.

The json i get is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "label": "de",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "fr",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "/de",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "/fr",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "Aktuell",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "fr/Aktuell",
    "visits": 80,
  },
  {
    "label": "index",
    "visits": 80,
  }
]
```

What i need is:

```
[
  {
    "label": "de",
    "visits": 160,
  },
  {
    "label": "fr",
    "visits": 160,
  },
  {
    "label": "Aktuell",
    "visits": 160,
  },
  {
    "label": "index",
    "visits": 80,
  }
]
```

The entries with labels "de" and "/de" as well as "fr" and "/fr" or "fr/Aktuell" and "Aktuell" need to be merged while other entries schould be kept the same like "index".

Is there a way to do this using d3? 
I guess only using javascript I would have to get the json file, then search for the entries, create a new entry and add up the numbers to then take the original json, delete those entries and add the new entries... although i also wouldn't know exactly how to do that either.

And it also isn't the best solution, since i have to generate a second object that will have to be processed and slows the whole system down. We are having performance issues already and i don't want to create new bottle necks.

Another problem is, that i need to be able to extend the list of entries that should be merged...

Is there a fast and simple way of doing this?

I know this seems like a "hey, i am too lazy, do it for me" post. 
I can assure you it isn't. It's more like a " i googled, i read, i tried, i sweared and i cried. now i am asking the professionals for help" post.

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to filter only on the last part of '/'. It was just an example. The filter would me more like: combine all [en, EN, /en, english, anglais] to one with label en. Also combine all [de, DE, /de, deutsch, german] to one with label de. Keep all others that are not combined.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript should be enough for this:

```
function clean(arr) {
    var obj = {}; 
    // obj will contain a map with keys being 'label' and value being 'visits'
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var labelParts = arr[i].label.split('/')
        var label = labelParts[labelParts.length-1]
        // Do a bit of filtering on the label

        if(typeof obj[label]!=='undefined') {
             obj[label] += arr[i].visits
        } else {
             obj[label] = arr[i].visits
        }
     }
     return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return {label:key,visits:obj[key]}; });
     // Re-create an array out of the object
}
```

I assumed you wanted to filter on the last part after '/'.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4peN9/2/

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is, that I don't want to filter only on the last part of '/'. It was just an example. The filter would me more like: combine all [en, EN, /en, english, anglais] to one with label en. Also combine all [de, DE, /de, deutsch, german] to one with label de. Keep all others that are not combined.

Comment: Then you'll only need to update the filtering part with exactly what you want. I guess you might need a collection of strings that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into D3's [nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) operations.  It shouldn't be too hard to specify the appropriate key and rollup functions to get what you want.  Something to the effect of:

```
var cleanup = function(l) {
    var i = l.indexOf("/");
    return i < 0 ? l : l.substring(i+1, l.length);
};
var getVisits = function(d) { return d.visits; };
var sum = function(a, b) { return a + b; };

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return cleanup(d.label); })
    .rollup(function(a) { return a.map(getVisits).reduce(sum); });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4peN9/3/

Answer (score 0):

I now wrote a quite ugly but functional javascript script for this. I am sure that it could be done more efficiently but this shall do for me atm.

And it goes something like this:

```
function clean(arr) 
  {
    mrgLst = [
      {
        "valid": "de",
        "invalid": ["/de"]
      },
      {
        "valid": "fr",
        "invalid": ["/fr"]
      },
      {
        "valid": "en",
        "invalid": ["/en"]
      },
      {
        "valid": "it",
        "invalid": ["/it"]
      },
      {
        "valid": "/index",
        "invalid": ["/index.html"]
      }
    ]

    var obj = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < mrgLst.length; i++) 
    {
      var valid = mrgLst[i].valid;
      var invalid = mrgLst[i].invalid;

      for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) 
      {
        var test0 = arr[j].label
        if (test0 == valid) 
        {
          var subObj = {};

          subObj["label"] = valid
          subObj["visits"] = arr[j].visits

          for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
          {              
            var test1 = arr[k].label
            for (x in invalid)
            {
              if (test1 == invalid[x])
              {
                subObj["label"] = valid
                subObj["visits"] += arr[k].visits
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (subObj != undefined)
      {
        obj.push(subObj)
      }

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
      var original = arr[i]
      var org = {}
      var dont = false

      for (var j = 0; j < mrgLst.length; j++)
      {
        var test0 = mrgLst[j].valid
        var test1 = mrgLst[j].invalid

        if (original.label == test0)
        {
          dont = true
        }
        for (x in test1) 
        {
          if (original.label == test1[x])
          {
            dont = true
          }
        }
      }

      if (dont == false)
      {
        org["label"] = original.label
        org["visits"] = arr[i].visits

        obj.push(org)
      }
    }
    return obj
  }
```

Just as reference for anybody that has a similar problem. Doesn't have much to do with d3 anymore but the output is used with d3...